# TypeError: jquery__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_0___default(...)(...).typeahead is not a function

Tags: webpack, typeahead.js

I just installed via `yarn install` the [typeahead.js](https://twitter.github.io/typeahead.js) libreary.

This is my app.js, you don't need to read all the code. It doesn't really matter:

```
import $ from 'jquery';
import 'typeahead';
const Bloodhound = require('imports-loader?define=>false!typeahead.js/dist/bloodhound.min.js');

$(document).ready(function () {
    var bestPictures = new Bloodhound({
        datumTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.obj.whitespace('value'),
        queryTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.whitespace,
        prefetch: 'http://twitter.github.io/typeahead.js/data/films/post_1960.json',
        remote: {
            url: 'http://twitter.github.io/typeahead.js/data/films/queries/%QUERY.json',
            wildcard: '%QUERY'
        }
    });
$('#custom-templates .typeahead').typeahead(null, {
    name: 'best-pictures',
    display: 'value',
    source: ['a'],
    templates: {
        empty: [
            '<div class="empty-message">',
            'unable to find any Best Picture winners that match the current query',
            '</div>'
        ].join('\n'),
        suggestion: function() {
            return '<div><strong>a</div>';
        }
    }
});
```

This is a part of my webpack config:

```
Encore
    .setOutputPath('web/' + buildFolder + '/')
    .setPublicPath('/' + buildFolder)
    .addEntry('app', './assets/js/app.js')
    .autoProvidejQuery()
    .enableSourceMaps(!Encore.isProduction())
    .enableVersioning(Encore.isProduction())
    .enableSassLoader()
    .enablePostCssLoader()
    .addPlugin(new CopyWebpackPlugin([
        {from: 'assets/img', to: './img'},
    ])).autoProvideVariables({
        $: 'jquery',
        jQuery: 'jquery',
              'window.jQuery': 'jquery'
    })
```

Unfortunately I'm getting this huge error:

> TypeError:
> jquery__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_0___default(...)(...).typeahead is not
> a function

I already tried this [solution](https://github.com/twitter/typeahead.js/issues/1627#issue-217042936) but I get the same issue.

Answer (score 2):

It is an import issue, you are importing it as a default, but this lib probably not exports itself as a default export.

One way to investigate it is to check what is the [`main`](https://github.com/twitter/typeahead.js/blob/master/package.json#L67) field inside the package.json
then follow to the `dist/typeahead.bundle.js` file as specified, and see that it uses a [UMD](https://www.davidbcalhoun.com/2014/what-is-amd-commonjs-and-umd/#umd-universal-module-definition) module definition, if you are using `import/export` syntax u will use the `module.exports = factory(require("jquery"));` [line](https://github.com/twitter/typeahead.js/blob/master/dist/typeahead.bundle.js#L13).

That means that you need to import this lib using

```
import * as typeahead from 'typeahead.js'
```

And you will get instance of the `typeahead` lib.

Looks like this specific lib has this issue in github, this is what solves it.
https://github.com/twitter/typeahead.js/issues/1627#issuecomment-406228429

Comment: I tried `import * as typehaed from 'typeahead'` but still same issue in fact I'm using webpack Encore and jquery is well loaded ia

Comment: You can debug the bundle that you get, check that jquery is provided properly.

Comment: §i dont understand why if I past th jquery.min.js and import rmally, everything work great but if I import it from the original pckage, i got that exception